# I would like to make an input/textarea text bold/italic when i clicked on a button bold/italic

Tags: javascript, dom, addeventlistener

I have taken a textarea where i will write someting.Then I will click on a button.And the text will turn bold.But it is not working.Here is my html and js code

````
   HTML :  <textarea cols="30" rows="10" id="textAreaText"></textarea>
      <button id="btn-bold">bold</button>
      <button id="btn-italic">italic</button>
  
  js:  <script>
 
document.getElementById('btn-bold').addEventListener('click',function (){
    const textArea=document.getElementById('textAreaText');
    const textAreaValue=textArea.value;
    textAreaValue.style.fontWeight="bold";
    console.log(textAreaValue);

})
</script>```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to style a string

right here the constant `textAreaValue` is holding a string that is not related to the DOM element,

to make it bold remove this line

```
        const textAreaValue= textArea.value;
```

instead your javascript should look like this

```
    const textArea=document.getElementById('textAreaText');
    textArea.style.fontWeight = "bold";
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it *italic* :

```
document.getElementById('textAreaText').style["font-style"]="italic"
```

To make it **bold** :

```
document.getElementById('textAreaText').style["font-weight"]="bold"
```